# Беседка может назваться «Ротонда»?

Tags: выбор-слов

«Беседка-ротонда» — круглая в плане беседка с куполом и колоннами. У меня в тексте кто-то ее назвал *беседкой «Ротонда».* Так ведь неправильно...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С заглавной буквы и в кавычках слово "ротонда" пишется только как название. **Ресторан "Ротонда".** Если данная конкретная беседка называется "Ротонда", то такое написание уместно. Во всех остальных случаях оно никакими правилами не предписывается.